# Execute this Strange function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project and I would like some help on how to execute this function in JavaScript.

I am not really familiar seeing '$' in code before a function in JS like that. what should I write in console if I am using a JS Engine such as Chrome of PhantomJS to execute this Function.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".cb-js-cc").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Overview.aspx/cc",
            data: "{ reservationVersionId: " + $('.js_ReservationVersionId').val() + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg && msg.d) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$()` is a reference to jQuery (though I'm confused because you seem to know this based on the tag in your question).

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-callback

Comment: this function is executed on dom ready event... why do you want to executed it manually?

Comment: Because I am making a Js Script that go to that website and AUTO DUMP msg.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `$(function () { ... } )` is shorthand notation for `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`.  That function will automatically execute when the page finishes loading, and will bind a click event to whatever element is tied to the class 'cb-js-cc'. Because the function is anonymous, you won't be able to trigger it via JavaScript code. If you need to programmatically trigger the event, you can use $.click():

```
$('.cb-js-cc').click();
```

Rewriting the function so it is not anonymous and can be executed at-will:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function myFunc() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Overview.aspx/cc",
            data: "{ reservationVersionId: " + $('.js_ReservationVersionId').val() + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg && msg.d) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    myFunc();
</script>
```

Comment: @victory `$('.cb-js-cc').click();`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I was just changing that :p. Thanks.

Comment: well, Its not really working with the JS code as you said. am I still possible to re code the function in Javascript and just execute it ?

Comment: okey your un-anonymous version of the code works well with my dump JS code now. thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to return msg.d rather than just alert it, I tried to replace alert() with return msg.d but it did not work. any ideas ?

Comment: You can't return the value from the success method. You need to keep a global variable for it. Declare the variable before the ajax call, and then set it to msg.d in the success method.